# creating link to rstudio installation of pandoc on mac

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, pandoc

I'm trying to use pandoc on a markdown document I'm working on at the command line on a mac. My Mac is telling me that I don't have pandoc installed. In fact, I know that pandoc *is* installed because I regularly use it from within Rstudio to knit rmarkdown or sweave files. I dealt with this problem on my desktop Ubuntu before and created a link from Rstudio's copy of pandoc to my `bin` so I could use it at the command line. However, I can't seem to find pandoc on my Mac. Does anyone know how I can create a link on a mac to make the Rstudio copy of pandoc accessible at the terminal line?

Comment: `/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc` but I'd really suggest using `homebrew` to properly install `pandoc` for the sytem.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do a brew install then. Can I ask why that's preferable?

Comment: the advantage of [homebrew and the installer](http://pandoc.org/installing.html) are that they provide newer versions of pandoc...

Comment: They also come with standard pandoc support directories in an accessible location: `/usr/local/Cellar/pandoc/pandocVERSION/`. It'll also work more consistently outside of RStudio and with other tools besides R (which you may inevitably use).